# Using apply method to modify a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

```
X,Y,Z
a,b,c
d,e,m
h,i,m
k,l,m
```

I want to be able to use the .apply method to call a function on this dataframe, so like `df.apply(modFunc())` to be able to change all the `m` values in column Z to `o`, so the result is

```
X,Y,Z
a,b,c
d,e,o
h,i,o
k,l,o
```

This is my try, so far I haven't found the solution:

```
def replaceFunc():
    df['X'] = df.X.str.replace("m", "o")

df.apply(replaceFunc())
```

Doing this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index STATION')
```

Answer (score 1):

If want use `apply` is possible add `axis=1` for processes by rows of `DataFrame`s:

```
def replaceFunc(x):
    x['Z'] = x.Z.replace("m", "o")
    return x

df1 = df.apply(replaceFunc, axis=1)
```

Your solution should be changed by [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for processing DataFrame in function:

```
def replaceFunc(x):
    x['Z'] = x.Z.str.replace("m", "o")
    return x

df1 = df.pipe(replaceFunc)
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = replaceFunc(df)
```

Comment: This will just return the modified df back to the OP. Are you sure this will also rectify the error that is there?